# Find dy/dx for an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Can someone walk me through how to find `dy/dx` (one of the problems I'm reviewing in my Calculus book):

$$\int_{1/x}^{2} t\sqrt{t-4} dt $$

I know I need my (x) value to be in the numerator so I can flip it and put a negative sign in front:

$$-\int_{2}^{1/x} t\sqrt{t-4} dt $$

Which is equivalent (as I understand it) to:

$$-\int_{2}^{x^{-1}} t\sqrt{t-4} dt $$

Do I then just start plugging in the `x^-1` for my `t`, or do I let `u=?` something???

Comment: Where is $y$ ??

Answer (score 2):

Here is the most general approach.

Let $$y = \int\limits_{\ell(x)}^{u(x)}f(t)\text{ d}t\text{.}$$
I use $u$ and $\ell$ to mean "upper" and "lower." 
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, we know that
$$\int\limits_{\ell(x)}^{u(x)}f(t)\text{ d}t = F(u(x)) - F(\ell(x))$$
where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, i.e., $F^{\prime} = f$. Now,
$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x} &= \dfrac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[F(u(x)) - F(\ell(x))\right] \\
&= F^{\prime}(u(x))u^{\prime}(x)- F^{\prime}(\ell(x))\ell^{\prime}(x) \text{ (chain rule)}\\
&= f(u(x))u^{\prime}(x) - f(\ell(x))\ell^{\prime}(x)\text{ since } F^{\prime} = f\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Hence, if $y = \displaystyle \int_{1/x}^{2}t\sqrt{t-4}\text{d}t$, then setting $u = 2$, $\ell = 1/x$, and $f = t\sqrt{t-4}$, we have
$$\dfrac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}  = f(u)u^{\prime}-f(\ell)\ell^{\prime} = f(2)\cdot 0 - f(1/x)\cdot(x) = -f(1/x)(-1/x^2) = -\dfrac{1}{x}\sqrt{1/x-4}(-1/x^2) = \dfrac{1}{x^3}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{x}-4}\text{.}$$

Comment: Ok, I'm following you now all the way up to the `f(u)u'-f(l)l'` portion. Can you detail out your steps more for plugging in the `2` and the `1/x` so I can better see how you came up with the final answer? On the `2` I keep seeing `f(2)` as `$$(2)\sqrt(2-4)$$`?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic Note that I didn't bother plugging in 2 because $u^{\prime} = 0$, so $f(2) \cdot u^{\prime}  = 0$. Sure, you can, but there's no point. As for $f(1/x)$, since $f(t) = t\sqrt{t-4}$, you get $\dfrac{1}{x}\sqrt{1/x-4}$, as indicated above.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$F(x)=\int t \sqrt{t-4} dt$$
$$f(x)=F'(x)=x\sqrt{x-4}$$
Then
$$y=\int_{\frac1x}^2 t \sqrt{t-4} dt=F(2)-F\left(\frac1x\right)$$
$$\frac{\text d y}{\text d x}=\frac{\text d \left(-F\left(\cfrac1x\right)\right)}{\text d x}$$
$$=-F'\left(\frac1x\right)\frac{\text d \left(\cfrac1x\right)}{\text d x}$$
$$=-f\left(\frac1x\right)\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\cfrac1x\sqrt{\cfrac1x-4}}{x^2}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{\cfrac1x-4}}{x^3}$$

Comment: Thanks for replying Kay. Would you mind detailing out the steps a bit more so I can ensure I am fully following after the `y=F(2)-F(1/x)` part?

Comment: Shouldn't the first line be something like $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}t\sqrt{t-4} dt$?

Comment: @Biggs Yes, you're right..

Answer (score 0):

With $F$ an antiderivative of the integrand,

$$y=F(2)-F\left(\frac1x\right).$$

Then with the chain rule,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\left(\frac1x\right)'F'\left(\frac1x\right)=\frac1{x^2}\frac1x\sqrt{\frac1x-4}.$$